# How tightly coupled is the compiler's brace-initializer-list to the type `std::initializer_list`?

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

Can I achieve the same effects without the C++ header `<initializer_list>`?

Does `class initializer_list` have to live in `namespace std` (does the compiler require this)?

I'm fine with a solution that works on the big five (GCC, MSVC, Intel, Clang, Comeau)

Comment: Nothing related to brace-initialization other than aggregate initialization works on MSVC.

Comment: I don't see what "solution" is needed here. Can you elaborate? So far I just see a couple of questions, but no problem you want to solve. It's far from clear what "same effect" means. `{1, 2}` has as little to do with `initializer_list<>`, as `dynamic_cast` has to do with `bad_cast`.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: I can't use initializer-list initialization with my own class (a language feature) without relying on `std::initializer_list`. `{1,2}`  has everything to do with `std::initializer_list` if I want to use that for my own class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's tightly coupled as per standard. It's a wrapper around a compiler-constructed array (though the standard doesn't say how precisely — GCC uses constructor with pointer and size, MSVC uses constructor with two points). And yes, it's required to be in namespace `std`, and in header `<initializer_list>`.

You'd have to see what constructors they use in each compiler you want to support and replicate that in your version, but TBH, I fail to see the point.

> The template `std::initializer_list` is not predeﬁned; if the header `<initializer_list>` is not included prior to a use of `std::initializer_list` — even an implicit use in which the type is not named (7.1.6.4) — the program is ill-formed.
>
> An object of type `std::initializer_list<E>` is constructed from an initializer list as if the implementation allocated an array of N elements of type E, where N is the number of elements in the initializer list.
>   Each element of that array is copy-initialized with the corresponding element of the initializer list, and the `std::initializer_list<E>` object is constructed to refer to that array.

Comment: Strange difference. Is that an ABI incompatibility?

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Well, GCC and MSVC don't have compatible ABIs to begin with, but I don't think the constructor would have made a difference.